# Hiding SSRS Nested Groups while showing detail row

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a hierarchical data set that looks like this:

```
Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4 Group5 Detail
Food   Fruit  Red    Apple         Apple
Food   Fruit  Orange Orange        Orange
Food   Meat   Red    Steak         Steak
Car    Honda  Red    2003   Civic  Civic
Car    Ford   Blue   2003   Escort Escort
```

My SSRS is a table with 5 groups and I have a parameter that filters "group1" column.  It's structured like this:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group4
Group5
Detail
```

When the report runs I want to be able to show all the groups that are not null.  For Food that would be group 1-4, for Cars that would be group 1-5.

My problem is when I try to hide group5 using the Visibility expression I don't get the detail row when the group is hidden.

How do I continue to show the detail row and hide the groups that are blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select a group in the group pane and select hidden=true, then no groups in the group hierarchy below that level will be rendered. You could filter the dataset leaving at least one group above details to allow details to render.