# How to hide a group and keep details?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I found this link: [Hiding SSRS Nested Groups while showing detail row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884481/hiding-ssrs-nested-groups-while-showing-detail-row#) but I can't quite figure the solution provided out.

I have a report that builds a summary of health conditions reported per location.
Initially it was just Location and the detail section had complaint followed by count and a subtotal.

They have asked to include age as well so It now does Location > Age > Details.  How do I make it so if they don't want to use age and just want the location, conditions, and summary details the grouping can turn off and the column can hide but the details remain?

Do I need to create a new report?  If I set the age grouping to hidden, the column stays behind and the details disappear.  Only the total for each site and the grand total appear.  If I add a new group above details, it disappears too.  If I add a new group above age, it appears with no details and the header is wrong.

What is the best way to continue?

Thanks,
Bil

To clarify:
Row groups: Location > Age
Details: Complaint > Count

4 columns in total.

Goal is to allow the 2nd column (Age) to disappear and the table to behave as if it wasn't grouping on age at all.  Maybe a check box on the parameter page or something logical to trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is actually rather simple once you realize how groups are working.  After reading https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263(v=sql.105).aspx I was able to figure it out.

I added a group to the age that was adjacent below.  This new group sorted by Condition.

Then I specified the visibility options on the Age rows and used a drop down saying "Group by Age".  For the function of visibility I use =NOT(Parameter) since the parameter is boolean True or False and we want the inverse of this for should we hide this row.

Then I did the reverse for visibility for the new complaint group.